# How to validate my MaterializeCSS form, and if first value in select selected - do not send form & display an error?

Tags: javascript, validation, materialize, forms

I have done the following form with MaterializeCSS:

```
<form action="num.php" method="GET" autocomplete="off">
<select id="num" name="num" class="browser-default">
<option selected="true" disabled selected>Select number 
</option>
<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>
</select>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Show
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that the user can click on the button,  without selecting a number. But I need that he first choose a value from the select, and only then press a button. And if he pressed a button without selecting a number (when "Select number:" selected), display an error and do not send the form. How can this be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for js. you can add `required` attribute to select and set value of Select number  to `""`

```html
<form action="num.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()"  method="GET" autocomplete="off">
<select required id="num" name="num" class="browser-default">
<option selected="true" value=""  disabled selected>Select number 
</option>
<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>
</select>
<button class="btn" id="btn" type="submit">Show
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the form reference and intercept the onsubmit event

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function() {

//check here the value and return false to stop the submit

if(document.getElementById('num').value == "")
   return false

}
```